# run multiple commands in parallel in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have few files and I have to cut few columns from that files to generate new files unix.
I tried to do it in loop as selecting files in directory and generating new files but as directory having 100 such files it takes lot of time to generate new files.

Can anyone please help if I can select 10 files in parallel and generate 10 new files and again next set of 10 files as it will reduce the time.

i need sample unix code block for this

```
cut -b 1-10,25-50,65-79 file1.txt > file_cut1.txt

cut -b 1-10,25-50,65-79 file2.txt > file_cut2.txt
```

Comment: You can start 10 instances of your processing code, sending them to background (see `&`).  Then monitor them.  When they are all done, start the next batch of 10.  Or - more sophisticated - start new instances as soon as some complete.  It will process faster, but more difficult to code.  Get started, when you have a specific issue, you can post a new question.

Comment: 100 files is nothing but of course that all depends on what sort of processing you are doing, how big the files are, your machine and the method you are using.  Can you post your current code that you are using?

Comment: Your example is not very helpful. If you run it 100 times, you will re-write the same `xyz.txt` 100 times. Please be more specific about input and output filenames.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that quite simply with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel 'cut -b 1-10,25-50,65-79 {} > {.}_cut.txt' ::: file*txt
```

where:

- `{}` represents the current filename, and
- `{.}` represents the current filename without its extension.

Make a backup of the files in your directory before trying this, or any unfamiliar commands.

It will process your files in parallel, doing `N` at a time, where `N` is the number of cores in your CPU. If you want it to do, say 8, jobs at a time, use:

```
parallel -j 8 ...
```

If you want to see what it *would* do, without actually doing anything, use:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

Comment: Adjust -j8 and be aware that more parallism is not always faster: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/